# Sudden failure on pip install of pyttsx3 NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyttsx3

I am unable to install pyttsx3 on windows , when i do pip install pyttsx3 I get the following errors
kindly help me , note that I have already run the command pip --upgrade setuptools

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2795, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2652, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 294, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 333, in prepare_files
    self._walk_req_to_install(
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 561, in _prepare_file
    set(req_to_install.extras) - set(dist.extras)
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2774, in extras
    return [dep for dep in self._dep_map if dep]
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2797, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2830, in _compute_dependencies
    common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2827, in reqs_for_extra
    if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
  File "c:\users\gamer\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\_markerlib\markers.py", line 113, in marker_fn
    return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
  File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined
```

Comment: which version of setuptools are you using?

Comment: Try installing it as an admin. also, try updating ```pip``` to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks a lot , It fixed the issue , kindly tell it as anwer so that I would upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating `setuptools`. Also, upgrade `pip` using `pip install --upgrade pip`. And try running the command as an admin.